# Error on installing matplotlib on Pyzo (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, installation

I have got problem with installing matplotlib and numpy library on my mac book. I tried to install those library but I got that message error and I don't know how to resolve it.
[My shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HoKT.png)

I already tried to uninstall and reinstall pyzo and miniconda but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, so I see the problem. It's not a python problem, it's more like a permissions error. It's like when you put a read-only mode on a file.

One way around this is to use Sudo. I am going to put 2 ways in the command in case one error out, so you might see some errors, but don't worry.

```sh
sudo pip install matplotlib && sudo -E pip install matplotlib
```

But really, just get pycharm, then you won't have to put up with this because of the VENV.

Comment: No Problem! Just Glad it helped.